# how to get hosted server(LAN) datetime in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

I have a web application, where users need to get the week number in a text box. Since the users/client machines are in different time zone, they are getting the week number based on their machine datetime. How can I call the hosted server datetime in javascript. So that I can convert the date to week in common, irrespective of client machine datetime.

**Hosted server is only connected in LAN, no internet access. Server Side language is PHP**

Please help.

Comment: You need to return the time from the server, either in the JS you are serving or via AJAX.

Comment: Server side language is PHP

Comment: Hello Brad. I need in javascript. Can u please explain.

Comment: @user220987 Have the server send back - either in a normal HTML response or via AJAX or whatever - the current time *with* timezone information (or even UTC if it is not important) or; return the server timezone and use moment.js to convert the local time to the server time.

Comment: if your server emits http Date headers, and it should, you can simply pull a head of location.href and new Date(xhr.getResponseHeader("date")) to grab the server time + ajax lag .

Comment: Be aware that there is an unknown amount of time spent in the "request -> response", so the returned date is from the past.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   window.date = new Date(<?php echo time();?> * 1000);
   window.now = new Date();
   window.getTime = function() {
      var n = new Date();
      n = n.getTime() - window.now.getTime();
      return new Date(window.date.getTime() + n);
   }
</script>
```

And then you can access it anywhere using window.getTime(), which uses your server time + how long they have been on your page

Answer (score 0):

here is an ajax-only way:

```
<script>
function sTime(callback) {
    callback=callback||alert;
    var XHRt = new XMLHttpRequest;
    XHRt.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (XHRt.readyState == 4 && XHRt.status == 200) {
            callback( new Date(XHRt.getResponseHeader("date")) , XHRt);
        }
    };
    XHRt.open("HEAD", location.href, true);
    XHRt.send();
    return XHRt;
} /* end aHead() */

//demo to show remote and local times:
sTime(function(dt){ alert( [dt, new Date].join("\n"));});
</script>
```

when i ran from firebug here, seems im about 1 second behind SO...